# How to fix the issue git commit diverged?

Tags: git

I am little bit familiar with git and and have successfully done the git clone, commit etc on my project. But now there is a complex situation comes in my project because of git. When i check the git status there is a message like

```
 Your branch and 'origin/develop' have diverged. and have 5 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
```

Also i am attaching here my git network diagrom [image: netwok flow diagrom]

Any body can help to fix this issue?

Comment: This is not a "complex" situation, this is a completely normal situation. If you're going branch, you've also got to merge. Branching and merging are as common and natural in Git as breathing.

Answer (score 2):

You should do a `git fetch origin` to get the latest commits from the origin repository locally.

Then, merge the latest commits from there into your own branch: `git merge origin/develop`. If some modifications in that branch affect the same files as some of the files you have modified, you may be prompted to perform certain merge operations manually (with a diff/merge tool) and commit them explicitly.

`git pull` combines both `fetch` and `merge` into a single operation, but I tend to prefer to fetch and then compare with `git diff` or `gitk` to estimate whether the merger is going to be difficult. I also tend to merge on a new branch (based on the one I'm currently working on), just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: There's very little benefit to merging on a new branch when you can just `git merge --abort` if there are messy conflicts.

Comment: @meagar, indeed, but it's probably not a bad idea to have a new branch for someone who's new to this. I find it makes it easier to see where you are and where you were during the merge process. Branches are cheap anyway.

Comment: When i try git merge --abort it shows me an error like "fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing)."

Comment: `git merge --abort` is only when something wrong happened during the merge.